# Powershell Write-Error Results

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Thanks for helping - input text file contains list of upz attribute values that i want to query against AD to discovery if they exist or not - I'm thinking by using Write-Error, when the query fails, the Write-Error "$line" will output to the file and I'll have the list of all users not in the directory.

If there is a better way - let me know - here is what i have so far (does not work yet) - is supposed to loop through the text file and output each successful find. Not sure how to build the IF statement with or without a Where-Object, and how to say 'does not exist in active directory'.

Create the file users_upz.ps1, with these lines, and create the C:\users_upz.txt file with the list of upz values (single value list of userid attribute value):

---

```
$UPZ = Get-Content "c:\users_upz.txt"
Write-Output $UPZ.count total lines read from file
ForEach ($line in $upz)
{
Write-Output "$line"
Get-QADObject -Service mydirectory.com:1234 -LdapFilter "(upz=$line)" -properties *|select *  
Write-Output "_____________________________________________"
} | Out-File 'c:\icomplyusers_upz.log'
```

---

to run: `powershell.exe users_upz.ps1`

Comment: Does this code work? Does it not output what you want? This code doesn't use `Write-Error` anywhere. Are you asking whether you should use `Write-Error`? What happens when the query fails? Does `Get-QADObject` return nothing? Does it throw an error? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run some code ONLY if a user doesn't exist?  Here we go, we've got a great tool in the Try/Catch/Finally construct that lets us try a command and if an error is encountered, proceed to the Catch block instead.  Modifying your code sample, we get the following.

```
ForEach ($line in $upz)
{
 Write-Output "$line"

 #Try says 'Run this, and if fails, hide the message and continue to the Catch block
 try {Get-QADObject -Service mydirectory.com:1234 -LdapFilter "(upz=$line)" `
      -properties * -ErrorAction Stop |select * }
 catch{Write-Warning "Displaying an error message if user not found"
      $errorusers += $line}
```

Now, what will happen is that we can put whatever code we want in the catch block.  As you can see, I've also added a snippet to collect all of the errors into an $errorusers object that you dump into a list at the end of your tool.

There are lots of options from this point on, I hope that this example helps you.  Please let me know if you need clarification on anything here.